# Why is my gaming desktop relatively slow at complex animation playback?

Tags: animation, performance

I’ve been working on an animation. Due to the large quantity of animated objects (plus a keyframed cloth simulaion), I noticed that when I played through the animation, it went slow. Really slow - about 1 frame/second.

I figured this was just my computer being old and relatively small, so I went to Best Buy and got a liquid-cooled gaming desktop for $1300. I figured it would speed up things.

However, after setting everything up and running the same file through my new PC, I noticed very little change. While the Cycles rendering time is a bit faster now, the amount of time to bake a simulation or even play through the animation has shown little to no improvement on this fabled new desktop.

Is there something I’m missing? It couldn't just be that the animation is too complicated, because it shows no improvement from my old PC. If this is really all it can do, why is it $1100 more than my regular old laptop which functions exactly the same? Is it just not the right kind of computer for the stuff I'm doing?

Here’s a link to the .blend file (it’s kind of big): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RWQbMgDf5_qzed-67kvOtq69nO4vGHD3/view?usp=sharing 2

Here are the PC specifications:

Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 16299)
Brand: iBuyPower

Chip type: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz (12 CPUs), ~3.2GHz

Memory: 16384MB RAM

Display Memory: 11138 MB

Available OS Memory: 16300MB RAM

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported

HDR: Not Supported

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your CPU usage during animation playback, most of your computer is not used.